# Display 2 Jenkins jobs build number in a single drop down

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have 3 Jenkins plan .
Plan **A , B,  C**

I need to display the build numbers of Plan **A and  B**  in Plan **C**'s Drop down.

I have displayed Plan A's build number in  Plan **C**'s Drop down. with the below code:

```
def jobname="A"
def list=[]
hudson.model.AbstractProject<?, ?> otherJob = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(jobname, hudson.model.AbstractProject.class)
hudson.util.RunList<?> builds = otherJob.getBuilds().overThresholdOnly(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
builds.each{run -> list.add(run.displayName) }
list
```

How to display 2 jobs( Plan A and B) build number in a single(Plan  C) drop down